# Sub menu in admin panel wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

**I'm new in wordpress hooks and i can not create a sub_menu like it**

[image]

i'm tryed the code below but's dont work
**`crud.php`**

```
 add_action('admin_menu', 'addAdminPageContent');

    function addAdminPageContent() {
      add_menu_page('CADASTRO', 'CADASTRO', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'crudAdminPage', 'dashicons-edit-page');
      add_submenu_page( 'crud.php',  'CURSOS', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'cursos', null );
    }

    function crudAdminPage(){ ....///
    function cursos(){....///
```

where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misleading the usage of [add_menu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) and [add_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) please refer their params. check below code.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'addAdminPageContent');
function addAdminPageContent() {
    add_menu_page('CADASTRO', 'CADASTRO', 'manage_options', 'cadastro', 'crudAdminPage', 'dashicons-edit-page');
    add_submenu_page( 'cadastro',  'CURSOS', 'CURSOS', 'manage_options', 'cursos', 'crudAdmiSubnPage' );
}

function crudAdminPage(){

}

function crudAdmiSubnPage(){
    
}
```

Comment: My route was wrong.  In the case in question I used the __file__ route as the first sub_menu parameters. Probably an error in the interpretation or translation of the documentation.  Thank you very much